# Change data record type of lookup field in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to change, depending an other field, the data record type of a lookup field.

Here my problem : I have a radio buttons field, where you can select "user" or "team". I need, when you select user, to display all users in a lookup, but if you select "team", I need to display all the "team"s in the same lookup.

Have you got an easy way to do it ?

Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom lookup field can only contain one type of related entity (unlike the owner or regarding fields supplied as part of the platform).

To achieve your requirement you need two lookups (attributes) on the entity, one related to `User` and the other to `Team`.  Add both of these lookups to the form.  When the user selects User or Team from the radio button run some javascript to show/hide the selected field type.  I'd also include some logic to ensure that on population of one field you clear the other.

You'll need to take the use of the two fields into account when writing any reports or queries.